# how express forming the img URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, express, handlebars.js

I have created a simple node solution which contains a form and on that submit the form it will display the image that is being inserted in the form.

**app.js**

```
    const app = express()
    app.use(express.static('public'))
    app.engine('hbs',handlebars({
    layoutsDir : __dirname + '/views/layouts',
    defaultLayout : "mainlayout",
    extname : "hbs",
    partialsDir : __dirname + '/views/partials'
    }))

    app.use("/uploader", imgUploader)
    app.set('view engine','hbs')
```

**impUpload.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const route = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

const Storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: './public/uploads',
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
}
})

const upload = multer({
storage: Storage,
fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    checkFileType(file, cb);
}
 }).single('myImage');

function checkFileType(file, cb) {
const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase())
const mimeType = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
if (extname && mimeType) {
    return cb(null, true)
}
else {
    cb('Error: Images Only!!!');
}
}

route.get("/", (req, res) => {
console.log("inside imgupload folder")
res.render("fileUpload")
})

route.post("/uploaded", (req, res) => {
upload(req, res, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        res.render("fileUpload", { message: error })
    }
    else {
        if (req.file == undefined) {
            res.render("fileUpload", { message: 'Please upload a file' })
        }
        else {
            res.render('fileUpload', { 
                message: 'File Uploaded Successfully', 
                file: `uploads/${req.file.filename}`                 
            });
        }
    }   
 })
 })
 module.exports = route
```

**fileUpload.js**

```
<div class="container"> 
<h1>file upload</h1>

{{message}}
<form action="/uploader/uploaded" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="file-field input-field">
  <div class="btn">
    <span>File</span>
    <input name="myImage" type="file">
  </div>
  <div class="file-path-wrapper">
    <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
  </div>
   </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn n">Submit</button>
 </form> 


 <br>
 </div>
 <div>
{{#if file}}
 <img src="{{file}}" class="responsive-img">
 {{/if}}
 </div>
```

Currently, my solution is structured as below

[image]

I am getting the error in the console

GET http://localhost:3000/uploader/uploads/myImage-1589223958713.PNG 404 (Not Found)

I am not getting why it's trying to find that img in the uploader/uploads although I have defined public folder in the app.js

But when trying the same code in the app.js it's working absolutely fine.

also if I try express().use(express.static(path.join(__dirname , '../public'))) in the imgupload.js then i am getting the error
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/arunoday/node/login_express_mongo/public/uploads/myImage-1589220613014.PNG

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am guessing the server has no access to those files or is not serving those files to the public? Maybe you need to make upload directory more accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just how browser's handle relative paths.

You have a Handlebars template that contains the following:
`<img src="{{file}}" class="responsive-img">`

The value of `file` is set to `uploads/${req.file.filename}`, which becomes something like `uploads/myImage-1589223958713.PNG`.

When your template is executed with above value for `file` you get:
`<img src="uploads/myImage-1589223958713.PNG" class="responsive-img">`

When the browser sees a relative URL, like `uploads/myImage-1589223958713.PNG`, it has to figure out the absolute URL. Since this relative URL does not begin with a `/`, the browser thinks it is a child path of the current page URL.

If the current page URL is `http://localhost:3000/uploaded/uploader`, the browser thinks your `uploads/myImage-1589223958713.PNG` URL is a child of `http://localhost:3000/uploader/` and so produces: `http://localhost:3000/uploader/uploads/myImage-1589223958713.PNG`.

To get the correct URL, you want to set the value for `file` so that it includes the full path:

```
file: `/uploads/${req.file.filename}`
```

Update:
Note that `/public` should not be included in the value for `file` because the `/public` directory is registered with express as a directory in which to look for static assets.

Comment: its working if i put file: `/uploads/${req.file.filename}`....why its not working if I add public folder ref in the file

Comment: Oh. Because you have registered `/public` as a static asset path. So express will look for assets in `/public`, but `/public` is not a part of the URL of the request. I will update my answer.