# Why does my styles get rejected when i change route inside my express nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, handlebars.js

This is my index.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const getRouter = require('./routes/getRoute')
const path = require('path');
const expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');
const app = express();

app.engine('hbs', expressHbs({
    defaultLayout: false
}));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
// app.set('views', 'views');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/get',getRouter.router);

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log('server has started on port: 3000')
})
```

And this is my getRouter.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');
const data = require('./data');

let message = `It's Working`;

router.get('/', (req,res,next)=>{
    res.render(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'views/index'), {msg: data.data.codename});
});



exports.router = router;
exports.message = message;
```

And finally, this is my index.hbs file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{msg}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Now whenever i change the route from `/` to basically anything like `/codename` inside getRouter.js , the styles inside index.hbs gets turned off somehow and only pain html is rendered.
Can someone help me figure this out as which part of the code is causing this? Thank you

Comment: I believe it is because the path to your CSS file is relative: `css/main.css`. So when you load the page `/codename`, the browser tries to load the CSS from `/codename/css/main.css`. So just add a slash to tell the browser that the CSS path is relative to the site root: `/css/main.css`.

Comment: I answered a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61741846/3397771

Comment: oh dear Lord, i just had to insert a `/` before `css/main.css` to make it an absolute path. your answered helped @76484 Thank you very much