# 404 page for different route doesn't work

Tags: css, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have created a site, that have root, help and 404 paths and pages in hbs format. The issue is that when I run `localhost:3000/wrong` it shows the site correctly but when I run `localhost:3000/help/wrong` the css part doesn't get applied to that 404 page as it should, because there is not route `/help/wrong`.

I run the code using `node app.js` or `nodemon app.js`.

Folder Structure:

> - public
>
>   - css
>
>     - styles.css
> - templates
>
>   - partials
>
>     - animal.hbs
>     - info.hbs
>   - views
>
>     - 404.hbs
>     - help.hbs
>     - index.hbs
> - app.js
> - package.json
> - package-lock.json

#### package.json

```
"dependencies": {
 "express": "^4.17.1",
 "hbs": "^4.1.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
}
```

#### app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const hbs = require("hbs");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', './templates/views');
hbs.registerPartials('./templates/partials');
app.use(express.static('./public'));

const animal = 'Tiger';
app.get('', (request, response, next) => {
    response.render('index', {
        title: 'Root',
        animal
    });
})

app.get('/help', (req, res) => {
    res.render('help', {
        title: 'Help',
        animal
    })
})

app.get('/help/*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('404', {
        title: '404',
        animal,
        error: 'Help Page Not Found!'
    })
})

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('404', {
        title: '404',
        animal,
        error: 'Page Not Found!'
    })
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is on port 3000");
})
```

#### index.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Root</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    {{>info}}
    {{>animal}}  
</body>
</html>
```

#### help.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Help</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    {{>info}}
    {{>animal}}
</body>
</html>
```

#### 404.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>404</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    {{>info}}
    {{error}}
    {{>animal}}
</body>
</html>
```

#### animal.hbs

```
<p>Animal is {{animal}}</p>
```

#### info.hbs

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<a href="/">Root</a>
<a href="/help">Help</a>
```

#### styles.css

```
body {
    background-color: teal;
}
```

I have tried explaining the question as best as possible. Please do comment if anything is not clear. Thank you so much.

Comment: The problem is the path to your CSS file. You want it to be relative to the site root, so it should start with a slash, as in `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62163971/why-does-my-styles-get-rejected-when-i-change-route-inside-my-express-nodejs-app#comment109943697_62163971 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/61741846/3397771

Comment: @76484 Thank you so much. I really didn't knew about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/help*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('404', {
        title: '404',
        animal,
        error: 'Help Page Not Found!'
    })
})
```

Does removing the `/` before the `*` do the trick?

Comment: No it didn't worked. After changing this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">` in every hbs file, it worked.