# Images not showing while using express.static

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am building Node Js app with handlebars templating engine in which I want to show images I have folder public/images In which I store all needed images for my website I've set this

```
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public","images")));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public")));
    app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

And in navbar.hbs file which is inside public/views/components I've put

```
<img src="{{loggedUser.avatar}}" alt="Avatar">
```

Image is not showing but if I place

```
     ../ before {{loggedUser.avatar}}
```

It is working but I want it to be like

```
    src="{{loggedUser.avatar}}"
```

because I want to show photos of users who logged with Google account also.

Comment: can you provide example of the variable content  ```{{loggedUser.avatar}}```  ?

Comment: I would bet that your value for `loggedUser.avatar` starts with `public` instead of `/public`. That starting slash is important because it tells the browser to request the image _relative to the site root_ rather than relative to the parent directory of the current document (ie., relative to the last `/` in the browser's address bar). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61741846/3397771

Comment: @AlanTishin I am keeping image name example : "istockphoto-965523228-612x612.jpg"

Comment: @76484 Just plain image name like mentioned above

Comment: It's not a good idea to have just the file name with no path because the browser is going to treat the file location as relative to the path in the address bar. For example, if you the path in the address bar is `/foo/bar`, then the image is going to be treated relative to the `/foo/` directory and be requested at `/foo/istockphoto-965523228-612x612.jpg`. In your src attribute you want to include the path to the image relative to the site root. In your example, it looks like your src should be `/public/{{loggedUser.avatar}}` or `/public/images/{{loggedUser.avatar}}`.