# Styling is not being applied to all hbs files

Tags: javascript, css, handlebars.js, partials, hbs

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlYuu.png)Doing a project were I'm using handlebars, and have the structure as shown on the picture.

On index.hbs and albums.hbs I'm using a partial, which I styled with style.css, linked on layout.hbs (code bellow).

```
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <nav class="navbar">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Homepage</a>
        </nav>
        {{{body}}}
      </body>
    </html>
```

However, my styling is being applied on index.hbs but not on album.hbs and I don't understand why... The css file should be correctly linked on layout.hbs because it is being applied to one of the files.

Here is the code on app.js

```
    app.set("view engine", "hbs");
    app.set("views", path.join(__dirname + "/views"));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));
    hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + "/views/partials");
```

Comment: I suspect it is because you need a staring slash in your css file path, as in `/styles/style.css`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61741846/3397771

Comment: Try this <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css" />