# Node Express application: CSS is not being applied for only one page

Tags: css, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm working on a node application using Handlebars.js (hbs) as my html templating language. I have a single CSS file located in a public folder. The .hbs files in my 'views' folder link to that CSS file and render just fine. However, the CSS is not being applied to one of my hbs files.

Here is my folder structure

```
 ┣ public
 ┃ ┣ css
 ┃ ┃ ┗ style.css
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ controllers
 ┃ ┣ routes
 ┃ ┗ server.js
 ┣ views
 ┃ ┣ auth
 ┃ ┃ ┣ login.hbs
 ┃ ┃ ┗ register.hbs
 ┃ ┣ home.hbs
 ┃ ┗ taskList.hbs
 ┣ .env
 ┣ package-lock.json
 ┗ package.json
```

Within my 'server.js' file, I've correctly served my static files like so:

```
app.use(express.static(pathToMyPublicFolder))
```

All the HBS files in the 'views' folder include a link to the stylesheet, and the CSS renders correctly:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
```

This head is exactly the same in 'taskLists.hbs', but no CSS is being applied. I even copy/pasted the header. No errors regarding the CSS link appear in the console either.

If you need more code or details, such as how I'm rendering each page, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use a starting slash `/` in your path so that it is not interpreted by your browser as relative to the address path: `/css/style.css`.

Comment: A post with a more detailed explanation (within the context of image files, rather than CSS files; but the concept is the same) can be found at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61741846/3397771

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could replace the link with `<style></style>` and paste the CSS code into there. I always put the CSS into the HTML when things happen, I hope it works for you :)