# CSS doesnt work when I pass a ID to my href

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

The css works when I remove the id from being added on the href. I'm wondering what I have to do to get it so I can pass the id to the page and have CSS working.

inside my server

```
app.get("/details/:id", (req, res) => {
  res.render("details",{
             style: "details"
             
  });
});
```

inside where my inventory page where passing the id on the end of the URL

```
<a href="./details/{{ID}}" class="card__link">Details</a>
```

finally where my CSS is being called in my main layout file

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />  
    <title>My Awesome App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./{{style}}.css" />
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="server.js"></script>  
  </head>
```

Comment: Making your CSS links be absolute so they start with `/`, not with `.`.  Then, they won't depend upon the path of your page.  You will, of course, also have to have express code to serve those CSS files (usually `express.static()` middleware).

Comment: An explanation of an issue similar to your - although with image paths instead of CSS - can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61741846/3397771

Comment: all my other css files work except this one and it has something to do with the /id on the end

Comment: I have also removed the . and fix the absolute path and it still wont work

Comment: Can you open the CSS file directly in your browser? What is the path to the file?