# 404 while rendering images using Handlebars.js on express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

Forgive me, I am new to JS, express, and handlebars!
I am building a project for a class, we're trying to render an image(logo) in hbs view, it is rendering in every view except one so far.

Using this code in the hbs:

```
<img src="./hangingPlant.png" class="h-[5rem] sm:h-[5rem]" alt="Logo" />
```

Added this to server.js:

```
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use(express.static('images'));
```

and all of the images are in an image directory in the repo.

So Basically this is how it is supposed to look, and does look on all views except for plant/id:
[correct display of logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLz0s.png)

And this is what I am seeing with a 404 error in the console:

[404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olwBD.png)

I tried adding all of the images into the public folder and using that instead, but that did not fix the problem. I changed the way the images were called. I even tried using only CSS to call the image and had no luck.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I can add the link to the repo if anyone wants to look at all of the files.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? What image path is generated (src attribute) when you inspect the missing image? In what way is that generated path different from the correctly generated image path in other views?

Comment: Please share more pieces of code so that we can debug the problem efficiently.

Comment: You want your image path to be `/hangingPlant.png`, not `./hangingPlant.png`. The `./` is telling the browser to look for the image relative to the current document's address path. When your document path includes a `/` in the path, like `plant/my-plant-id`, the browser looks for the image at `plant/hangingPlant.png`. A relevant post can be viewed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61741846/3397771